# Маршрутизация через ipip-туннель

Tags: linux, сеть, администрирование, маршрутизация

Есть банальная задача: Соединить два centos7 сервера ipip-туннелем и смаршрутизировать через него локальные сети друг друга, но что-то у меня не получается на этапе маршрутизации и интерфейс br0 (или br1) 10.10.0.1/24 на host1 не видит интерфейс br0 (или br1) 10.20.0.1/24 на host2, ниже подробнее...

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я забыл? Где ошибка?

**Дано: host1**

```
#ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:ae:37:c3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.76/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 258553sec preferred_lft 258553sec
    inet6 fe80::3d29:1cc:c1ca:7437/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:61:b6:cf:1e:14 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: dummy1: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 36:6f:b9:86:64:22 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:b8:91:9f:dc:91 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.0.1/24 brd 10.10.0.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::50b8:91ff:fe9f:dc91/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: br1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:57:44:16:57:d2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.1.1/24 brd 10.10.1.255 scope global br1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::57:44ff:fe16:57d2/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
8: tun0@NONE: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1480 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/ipip 192.168.0.76 peer 192.168.0.77
    inet 192.168.254.1 peer 192.168.254.2/30 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN 
    link/ether 02:42:8b:75:9a:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

#ip r s
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp0s3 proto static metric 100 
10.10.0.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.0.1 
10.10.1.0/24 dev br1 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.1.1 
10.20.0.0/24 dev tun0 scope link 
10.20.1.0/24 dev tun0 scope link 
169.254.0.0/16 dev br0 scope link metric 1005 
169.254.0.0/16 dev br1 scope link metric 1006 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.76 metric 100 
192.168.254.0/30 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.254.1 
192.168.254.0/24 dev tun0 scope link 

# ip ru
0:  from all lookup local 
32763:  from 192.168.254.1 lookup tabletun0 
32764:  from all to 10.20.1.0/24 lookup tabletun0 
32765:  from all to 10.20.0.0/24 lookup tabletun0 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default 

# ip r s t tabletun0
default dev tun0 scope link 

# iptables-save 
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Tue May 22 04:35:45 2018
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue May 22 04:35:45 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Tue May 22 04:35:45 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [41:2780]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [21:2188]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue May 22 04:35:45 2018
```

**Дано: host2**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:ae:37:c3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.77/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global enp0s3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feae:37c3/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether da:ec:60:9c:fc:91 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: dummy1: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 72:77:8b:b5:8b:1e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether da:ec:60:9c:fc:91 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.20.0.1/24 brd 10.20.0.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d8ec:60ff:fe9c:fc91/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
7: tun0@NONE: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1480 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/ipip 192.168.0.77 peer 192.168.0.76
    inet 192.168.254.2 peer 192.168.254.1/30 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: br1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 8a:4e:6e:00:3e:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.20.1.1/24 brd 10.20.1.255 scope global br1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::884e:6eff:fe00:3e24/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


#ip r s
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp0s3 proto static metric 100 
10.10.0.0/24 dev tun0 scope link 
10.10.1.0/24 dev tun0 scope link 
10.20.0.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 10.20.0.1 
10.20.1.0/24 dev br1 proto kernel scope link src 10.20.1.1 
169.254.0.0/16 dev br0 scope link metric 1005 
169.254.0.0/16 dev br1 scope link metric 1008 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.77 metric 100 
192.168.254.0/30 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.254.2 
192.168.254.0/24 dev tun0 scope link 


# ip ru
0:  from all lookup local 
32765:  from 192.168.254.2 lookup tabletun0 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default 


# ip r s t tabletun0
default dev tun0 scope link


# iptables-save 
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon May 21 14:27:29 2018
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [85:7608]
:INPUT ACCEPT [16:2688]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2:152]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2:152]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon May 21 14:27:29 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon May 21 14:27:29 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [20:1467]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [11:1104]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon May 21 14:27:29 2018
```

**Диагностика с host1**

```
# ping 10.20.1.1
PING 10.20.1.1 (10.20.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.20.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.417 ms
64 bytes from 10.20.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.28 ms

# tcpdump -nni any not port 22
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
04:41:36.016368 IP 192.168.0.63.137 > 192.168.0.255.137: NBT UDP PACKET(137): QUERY; REQUEST; BROADCAST
04:41:36.159857 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.0.76 tell 192.168.0.77, length 46
04:41:36.159947 ARP, Reply 192.168.0.76 is-at 08:00:27:ae:37:c3, length 28
04:41:36.834556 IP 192.168.0.63.137 > 192.168.0.255.137: NBT UDP PACKET(137): QUERY; REQUEST; BROADCAST
04:41:37.552177 IP 192.168.0.63.137 > 192.168.0.255.137: NBT UDP PACKET(137): QUERY; REQUEST; BROADCAST
04:41:37.805327 IP 192.168.254.1 > 10.20.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 1743, seq 1, length 64
04:41:37.805345 IP 192.168.0.76 > 192.168.0.77: IP 192.168.254.1 > 10.20.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 1743, seq 1, length 64 (ipip-proto-4)
04:41:37.805663 IP 192.168.0.77 > 192.168.0.76: IP 10.20.1.1 > 192.168.254.1: ICMP echo reply, id 1743, seq 1, length 64 (ipip-proto-4)
04:41:37.805713 IP 10.20.1.1 > 192.168.254.1: ICMP echo reply, id 1743, seq 1, length 64
04:41:38.805772 IP 192.168.254.1 > 10.20.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 1743, seq 2, length 64
04:41:38.805815 IP 192.168.0.76 > 192.168.0.77: IP 192.168.254.1 > 10.20.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 1743, seq 2, length 64 (ipip-proto-4)
04:41:38.806769 IP 192.168.0.77 > 192.168.0.76: IP 10.20.1.1 > 192.168.254.1: ICMP echo reply, id 1743, seq 2, length 64 (ipip-proto-4)
04:41:38.806970 IP 10.20.1.1 > 192.168.254.1: ICMP echo reply, id 1743, seq 2, length 64
04:41:39.496721 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.0.113 tell 192.168.0.123, length 46


# ip r get 10.20.1.1
10.20.1.1 dev tun0 src 192.168.254.1 
    cache expires 396sec mtu 1480 


# ping 10.20.1.1 -I br0
PING 10.20.1.1 (10.20.1.1) from 10.10.0.1 br0: 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.20.1.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms

# tcpdump -nni any not port 22
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
04:43:34.401275 ARP, Request who-has 10.20.1.1 tell 10.10.0.1, length 28
04:43:35.403213 IP 10.10.0.1 > 10.10.0.1: ICMP host 10.20.1.1 unreachable, length 92
04:43:35.403238 IP 10.10.0.1 > 10.10.0.1: ICMP host 10.20.1.1 unreachable, length 92
04:43:35.403254 IP 10.10.0.1 > 10.10.0.1: ICMP host 10.20.1.1 unreachable, length 92
04:43:35.403269 IP 10.10.0.1 > 10.10.0.1: ICMP host 10.20.1.1 unreachable, length 92
04:43:36.397348 ARP, Request who-has 10.20.1.1 tell 10.10.0.1, length 28
04:43:36.708938 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.0.76 (08:00:27:ae:37:c3) tell 192.168.0.83, length 46
04:43:36.708997 ARP, Reply 192.168.0.76 is-at 08:00:27:ae:37:c3, length 28
04:43:37.399550 ARP, Request who-has 10.20.1.1 tell 10.10.0.1, length 28
04:43:38.401714 ARP, Request who-has 10.20.1.1 tell 10.10.0.1, length 28
04:43:39.403103 IP 10.10.0.1 > 10.10.0.1: ICMP host 10.20.1.1 unreachable, length 92
04:43:39.403128 IP 10.10.0.1 > 10.10.0.1: ICMP host 10.20.1.1 unreachable, length 92
04:43:39.403144 IP 10.10.0.1 > 10.10.0.1: ICMP host 10.20.1.1 unreachable, length 92
04:43:39.403157 IP 10.10.0.1 > 10.10.0.1: ICMP host 10.20.1.1 unreachable, length 92
04:43:39.512526 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.0.113 tell 192.168.0.123, length 46
```

Comment: 1. `FORWARD DROP` 2. `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` 3. наверняка потребуется и `snat/masquerade`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Вы имеете ввиду, что надо forwarding вырубить? Пробовал, не получается: `iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP ; echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` Пробовал и nat/masquerade настроить - не получается

Comment: forwarding надо включить.

Comment: дык он по-дефолту включен и политика ACCEPT - не работает

Comment: forwarding надо включить на обеих машинах. и политики `forward drop` не должно быть в netfilter-е.

Comment: До второй машины трафик не доходит, в `tcpdump` его нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `$ ping -I br0 10.20.1.1`

насколько я понял вопрос, вас смущает, что эта команда «не работает».

но она и не должна «работать». ведь опцией `-I` вы указали отправлять пакеты через сетевей интерфейс `br0`. а ведь у вас адреса `10.20.1.0/24` доступны на интерфейсе `tun0`.

потому

```
$ ping 10.20.1.1
```

и «работает нормально», отправляя пакеты как раз на нужный интерфейс (`tun0`). конечно, вы можете указать его и явно:

```
$ ping -I tun0 10.20.1.1
```

---

а для того, чтобы клиенты из одной сети могли «достучаться» до клиентов из другой сети, **у тех и у других** должен быть соответствующий маршрут, проходящий через один из настраиваемых вами компьютеров: либо умолчальный, либо эксклюзивный к «соседской» сети (ведь должны же клиенты «знать», куда слать пакеты и ответы на них).

Comment: Меня смущает, то что в действительности связности между сетями нет, и даже в пределах одного бриджа и я уже не знаю что делать. Для примера назначаем адрес 10.10.0.10 dummy0 и включаем его в br0 на host1, далее создаём виртуальный интерфейс с помощью netns вот таким образом https://pastebin.com/57ZdaDDM и включаем его тоже в br0 ну и дальше из netns выполняем ping либо бриджа 10.10.0.1 либо dummy0 - и получаем ни-че-го (`ARP, Request who-has` то же, что в топике) - вот это меня действительно смущает.

Comment: Высшая цель, организовать связность из сетей 10.10.0.0/24 br0 host1 и 10.10.1.0/24 br1 host1 до сетей 10.20.0.0/24 br0 host2 и 10.20.1.0/24 br1 host2 через IPIP-туннель, чтоб на host1 в бриджах посадить грядку docker, а на host2 в бриджах грядку kvm. Так вот связности нет ни из бриджей, ни даже внутри бриджей. Связность есть только с хостов у адресов туннеля до этих сетей. В общем, всё очень плохо.

Comment: При этом, если проверять вот так `ping 10.20.0.1 -I 10.10.0.1` то есть вместо `ifname` указывать `адрес`, то связность есть вообще всего со всем. Я уже понять вообще ничего не могу: Как правильно всё-таки проверять доступность из сети с одного бриджа в сеть с другого бриджа? FACEPALM

Comment: что-то вы усложняете себе жизнь, пытаясь одним махом «съесть слона». разбейте одну громадную задачу на маленькие под-задачи и решайте их. пример мелкой подзадачи: «добиться хождения пакетов между клиентом и ip-адресом, закреплённым за ipip-туннелем с ближайшей к нему стороны», «добиться того же для дальней стороны», «добиться хождения пакетов между клиентом и любыми другими адресами шлюза на дальней стороне ipip-туннеля». и не злоупотребляйте опцией `-I` (мне она в реальной жизни вообще ни разу не понадобилась, если склероз не подводит).

Comment: Ок, допустим. Подскажите тогда, почему не работает такой вариант `[host1 eth0: 10.10.0.100/24] ----> [host2 br1 (eth0 + eth1)] <==== [host3 eth0: 10.10.0.200/24]` : 3 виртуальные машины, на двух в разных внутренних сетях есть ip адреса с одного пула адресов /24, на одной просто бридж соединяющий эти две сети. При ping с первой на третью я вижу `ARP Request` и вижу `ARP Replay`, но уже на второй машине (та, что в середине) `ARP Reply` уже нет. В чём тут дело? Как Вы и сказали, разбил задачу на маленькие...

Comment: не влезла в предыдущий комментарий добавка: и задавайте отдельные вопросы (буде возникнут) по каждой мелкой подзадаче. так тут принято. чем «мельче» вопрос — тем лучше (потому что тем больше шансов, что он может пригодиться кому-либо ещё помимо автора).